# Add Silex Application to Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I would like to extend Silex Application in a Symfony bundle.

So I add my silex application in the composer of my Symfony2 website.

The silex application is in the vendor, but how can I add it in appKernel of my Symfony ?

The Silex application don't have "bundle name", and I need it to do something like :

```
class ownBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'mySilexApp';
    }
}
```